# Accessing bytesIO object after creation

Tags: python, pdf

I am working on a scrapy spider, trying to extract text multiple pdfs in a directory, using slate (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate). I have no interest in saving the actual PDF to disk , and so I've been advised to look into the io.bytesIO subclass at https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams. Based on [Creating bytesIO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799009/creating-and-accessing-bytesio-object/39799090#39799090) , I have initialized the bytesIO class with the pdf body, but now I need to pass the data to the slate module. So far I have:

```
def save_pdf(self, response):
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(response.body)

    with open(in_memory_pdf, 'rb') as f:
        doc = slate.PDF(f)
        print(doc[0])
```

I'm getting:

```
in_memory_pdf.read(response.body)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'
```

How can I get this working?

edit:

```
with open(in_memory_pdf, 'rb') as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found
```

edit 2:

```
def save_pdf(self, response):
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))
    in_memory_pdf.seek(0)
    doc = slate.PDF(in_memory_pdf)
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Try `in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the initial problem!

Comment: Try using [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) instead of `BytesIO`. Also note that with either, you don't need the `with open(...) as f`, just rewind it to the beginning after creation with `in_memory_pdf.seek(0)` and then use `in_memory_pdf` _instead_ of `f`.

Comment: Thanks , the StringIO part didn't work but the seek(0) part did the trick. I've added the final code above. How did you know the context manager was not needed?

Comment: I knew a context manager wasn't needed because the object created (of either kind) isn't really a file and therefore didn't need to be `open`ed, and since it's assigned to variable (`in_memory_pdf`) would be cleaned-up (closed, deleted, and garbage-collected) automatically without any extra help. Once created, both act like a _file_ opened in either `'rb'` or `'r'` mode respectively, but without any associated filename. Guess I learned most of that by reading the documentation and looking at the example code in it.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the `in_memory_pdf.seek(0)` **might** not really be necessary because the virtual file just created may already be positioned there. The documentation doesn't mention what the initial state is, so I suggested putting one just in case it's not (since it probably doesn't affect performance much doing so).

Answer (score 1):

You already know the answer. It is clearly mentioned in the Python TypeError message and clear from the documentation:

```
class io.BytesIO([initial_bytes])
```

BytesIO accepts bytes. And you are passing it contents. i.e: response.body which is a string.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful info! I used in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body)) from above. The problem now is I'm getting an error added above.

Comment: Your solution is pretty much given by the error itself. You are passing string of bytes. Concert it to int as the error says. It should work given that bytes work.