# Opening a pdf bytestring for reading

Tags: python, pdf

I am working on a scrapy spider, trying to convert pdfs, using pdfminer (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer2). I have no interest in saving the actual PDF to disk , and so I've been advised to look into the io.bytesIO subclass at https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams. Based on [Creating bytesIO object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799009/creating-and-accessing-bytesio-object/39799090#39799090) , I have initialized the bytesIO class with the pdf body, but now I need to open the data and follow and example like the basic usage http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html So far based on http://zevross.com/blog/2014/04/09/extracting-tabular-data-from-a-pdf-an-example-using-python-and-regular-expressions/ I have:

```
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))
    in_memory_pdf.seek(0)

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()

    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(in_memory_pdf, 'rb')

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    st = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    print st
```

When I run this I get:

```
fp = file(in_memory_pdf, 'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found
```

How can I open this pdf bytestring for processing?

After the suggested change I'm getting:

```
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: exec: ET
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: nexttoken: (2819L, /'Q')
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: do_keyword: pos=2819L, token=/'Q', stack=[]
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: add_results: ((2819L, /'Q'),)
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: nextobject: (2819L, /'Q')
2016-10-17 23:59:35 [root] DEBUG: exec: Q

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\j1\spiders\j1_spider.py", line 235, in parse_pdf_to_html
    interpreter.process_page(page)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 835, in process_page
    self.device.end_page(page)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 53, in end_page
    self.receive_layout(self.cur_item)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 206, in receive_layout
    render(ltpage)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 196, in render
    render(child)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 196, in render
    render(child)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 196, in render
    render(child)
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 198, in render
    self.write_text(item.get_text())
  File "C:\\site-packages\pdfminer\converter.py", line 189, in write_text
    self.outfp.write(text)
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Comment: Try change `fp = file(in_memory_pdf, 'rb')` to `fp = in_memory_pdf`.

Comment: This partially worked, please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `in_memory_pdf` is already a file-like object for `str` (or `bytes` in Py3), can be directly used without opening. Thus changing `fp = file(in_memory_pdf, 'rb')` to `fp = in_memory_pdf` partially worked.
2. The second parameter of `TextConverter` should also be a file-like object for `str` (or `bytes` in Py3). But `retstr` in the question is for `unicode` (or `str` in Py3). Therefore `retstr = StringIO()` should be changed to `retstr = BytesIO()`.